# (apply #'and '(t t t)) is throwing an error. Why?

Tags: elisp-macros

```lisp
(apply #'and '(t t t))
```

gives me

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function #<subr and>)
  and(t t t)
  apply(and (t t t))
```

while

```lisp
(and t t t)
```

gives me `t`.

What am I missing?

This is with `emacs -Q` on

```
In GNU Emacs 30.0.50 (build 11, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version
 3.24.34, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2023-07-24 built on debian
Repository revision: acebaa793f1b18ad54bccffe7ad07fef8e1cebe1
Repository branch: master
Windowing system distributor 'The X.Org Foundation', version 11.0.12101007
System Description: Debian GNU/Linux bookworm

Configured using:
 'configure --with-imagemagick --with-xwidgets --with-json
 --without-compress-install --with-tree-sitter
 --with-native-compilation=no'

Configured features:
ACL CAIRO DBUS FREETYPE GIF GLIB GMP GNUTLS GPM GSETTINGS HARFBUZZ
IMAGEMAGICK JPEG JSON LCMS2 LIBOTF LIBSELINUX LIBSYSTEMD LIBXML2
M17N_FLT MODULES NOTIFY INOTIFY PDUMPER PNG RSVG SECCOMP SOUND SQLITE3
THREADS TIFF TOOLKIT_SCROLL_BARS TREE_SITTER WEBP X11 XDBE XIM XINPUT2
XPM XWIDGETS GTK3 ZLIB

Important settings:
  value of $LANG: en_IN
  value of $XMODIFIERS: @im=ibus
  locale-coding-system: iso-latin-1-unix
```

---

With `M-x slime` and `sbcl` I get,

```
; SLIME 2.28
CL-USER> (apply #'and '(t t t))
```

and

```
COMMON-LISP:AND is a macro, not a function.
   [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]

Restarts:
 0: [CONTINUE] Retry using AND.
 1: [USE-VALUE] Use specified function
 2: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 3: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 4: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD tid=3919 "repl-thread" RUNNING {100193E373}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (SB-KERNEL:%COERCE-NAME-TO-FUN AND)
  1: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (FUNCTION AND) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  2: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (APPLY (FUNCTION AND) (QUOTE (T T T))) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  3: (EVAL (APPLY (FUNCTION AND) (QUOTE (T T T))))
```

---

My understanding was that `macro`-s are also functions which map from `sexp` to `sexp`.

---

`sbcl`error suggests that I cannot `apply` on a `macro`.  Let me see what else I find.  Looks like my "mental model" of lisp macros requires further refinement.

---

The docstring of `and` say this

`and` is a special form in `C source code`.

```lisp
(and CONDITIONS...)
```

Eval args until one of them yields nil, then return nil.
The remaining args are not evalled at all.
If no arg yields nil, return the last arg’s value.

Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 19.20.  This function has a `byte-compile` property `byte-compile-and` and a byte-code optimizer `byte-optimize-and`.  See the manual for details.

And the entry to `(info "(elisp) Advice and Byte Code")`  (see [13.12.5 Advice and Byte Code](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advice-and-Byte-Code.html)) says

`File: elisp.info, Node: Advice and Byte Code, Prev: Porting Old Advice, Up: Advising Functions`

### 13.12.5 Advice and Byte Code

Not all functions can be reliably advised.  The byte compiler may choose to replace a call to a function with a sequence of instructions that doesn’t call the function you were interested in altering.

This usually happens due to one of the three following mechanisms:

- `byte-compile` properties: If a function’s symbol has a `byte-compile` property, that property will be used instead of the symbol’s function definition.
- `byte-optimize` properties: If a function’s symbol has a `byte-optimize` property, the byte compiler may rewrite the function arguments, or decide to use a different function altogether.
- `compiler-macro`: declare forms A function can have a special `compiler-macro` `declare` form in its definition (*note Declare Form::) that defines an “expander” to call when compiling the function.  The expander could then cause the produced byte-code not to call the original function.

---

`SBCL` is very clear that `and` is a `macro`.

`Elisp` says `and` is a special form.  Saying `and` is a `special form` amounts to waving your hand, and saying "I will do whatever I please with the arguments you provide".

See `(info "(elisp) Special Forms")` [10.2.7 Special Forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Forms.html)

File: elisp.info, Node: Special Forms, Next: Autoloading, Prev: Macro Forms, Up: Forms

### 10.2.7 Special Forms

A “special form” is a primitive specially marked so that its arguments are not all evaluated.  Most special forms define control structures or perform variable bindings—things which functions cannot do.

**Each special form has its own rules for which arguments are evaluated and which are used without evaluation.  Whether a particular argument is evaluated may depend on the results of evaluating other arguments.**

If an expression’s first symbol is that of a special form, the expression should follow the rules of that special form; otherwise, Emacs’s behavior is not well-defined (though it will not crash).  For example, `((lambda (x) x . 3) 4)` contains a subexpression that begins with `lambda` but is not a well-formed `lambda` expression, so Emacs may signal an error, or may return 3 or 4 or `nil`, or may behave in other ways.

*Just adding the above notes that someone or I myself can fill in the gaps in the argument ...*

---

I find it strange that there is no function to do a boolean `and` operation.  I think there should be a function for doing `boolean` arithmetic.  Boolean operations are used as part of control flow, but lisp's way of intermixing boolean operations with control flow is something I find strange.

For now I went with

```lisp
(require 'dash)
(require 'cl-extra)
(->> (-zip-lists '(1 2)
                 '(4 1))
     (--map (->> it
                 (apply #'<)))
     (cl-every #'identity))
```

`cl-every` defined in `cl-extra` is a function, and it is useful to look at its implementation to see how boolean arithmetic is done.

Does anyone know if `dash` or some other library allows sorting of a list of list of obects.  If there is one, I will directly use it.  I know that the `tabulated-list` or `tablist` or even `org-table` provides sorting based on multiple columns.  It should be there somewhere ...

Comment: Just a suggestion: please remove the text following "*This is with `emacs -Q` on*". The emacs version/build-information you provided makes no sense, because this (what you do will signal an error) is **defined behavior** and **is true for any released version**. And your question is about ELisp, not Common Lisp. They are different, so **it is not surprising that they behave differently**. Any irrelevant text will dilute the key information of your question, and will make readers spend more unnecessary time.

Comment: I have added reason why i have added the Emacs version ...   In your answer,  I think you are missing steps in your reasoning.  Again that is my humble opinion ... `and` gets passed in as `data` to `apply`, and only when the runtime tries to invoke `and` it doesn't find it.    That is how your argument should go ... and not the way it is worded.  It is possible that I myself have to make my argument my coherent.  Any answer should explain why `and` function (or `macro`) is not available at runtime.

Comment: "I find it strange that there is no function to do a boolean and operation" -- it is certainly *not* strange that `and` is not a function, because *all arguments must be evaluated* before a function call, whereas it's crucial to `and` that only as many arguments as necessary be evaluated.  If you did want a *function* which performed a boolean and for all of its evaluated arguments you could certainly write one, but `(not (memq nil ARGS))` is already pretty trivial.

Comment: @shynur: You should add the information from the first comment above *to the answer*, pointing out that the version information does not make any difference. But as a general point, we *want* people to record their Emacs version with the question: the OP might not know whether it makes a difference or not, but if it does, it saves a round-trip of me asking in a comment and the OP adding that version to the question. We certainly don't want gobs of irrelevant information in the question, but the version info is minimal and often useful.

Comment: @NickD: "*OP might not know whether it makes a difference or not, but if it does, it saves a round-trip of me asking in a comment and the OP adding that version to the question.*" -- I hadn't thought of that. You're right. Thank you

Comment: The error report provided by `sbcl` is more palatable than what  `elisp` provides.  Definitely there is scope for improvement.  Or it is possible that the implementation of `elisp` doesn't at all provide any scope for improving on the error message that is already provided.

Comment: @phils even after re-reading your message I am not convinced that I shouldn't be surprised by there no being a runtime function for boolean `and`.  Whether that function is short-circuiting or is  a matter of expedience.  I believe a remark like "this is not strange", implies that there is an assumption being made on what the "norm" is.  And I am sure you agree that what passes off as "normal" depends on which world you live in mostly.

Comment: For sure, "the norm" is always going to depend on the context, and the context here is Lisp, and I wouldn't expect `and` to be a function in *any* Lisp.  Imagine `(and ok-to-delete (delete-it-all))` if `and` was a function, for instance.  In Lisp it's necessary that the likes of `and` and `or` do not unnecessarily evaluate all of their arguments, and therefore they cannot be functions.

Comment: The point I was wanting to make was not that there *shouldn't* be a function (I have no real opinion on that), but rather that if there *were* a function it couldn't be `and` specifically, because the requirements for `and` in Lisp are in conflict with how functions work in Lisp (which I believe is more or less the answer to your question).

Comment: OP: when you quote, please trim the quote to what's relevant to the question at hand and use `> ` markup (or similar) to differentiate between what you write and what you quote.

Comment: @mxnt you are asking multiple questions, here. You ask "what am I missing" and then "are there libraries that do something else." Please make sure you ask one and only one question here, so that we can provide you with one and only one answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OP:

> why is `(apply #'and '(t t t))` not equivalent to `(and t t t)`

Follow *your* logic, `(apply #'print '(wryyyy))` is equivalent to 
`(print wryyyy)` instead of `(print 'wryyyy)`.
But this is wrong.  (You can test it yourself.)
`apply` doesn't work this way.

---

> `(apply #'and '(t t t))` is throwing an error. Why?

Because `and` is a *special form* (plz `C-h f and` yourself).
What is a *special form*?

```lisp
(and nil (balabala ...))
```

won't signal an error, but

```lisp
(and (balabala ...))
```

will.

As you can see, *special form* can receive arguments without evaluating them -- when `and` encounters a `nil`, it knows that there is no need to evaluate anymore because the result of `(and nil ...)` is **definitely `nil`**.
This is called *short-circuit evaluation*; it is a defined behavior and is not a bug of version 30.

But `apply` will always evaluate its arguments.
So what you do make `and` no longer use short-circuit evaluation.

---

As contrast, `(not (memq nil ARGS))` as mentioned by @phils or

```lisp
(defun another-and (&rest booleans)
  (if (null booleans)
      t
    (when (car booleans)
      (apply #'another-and (cdr booleans)))))
```

is what you want.

Comment: There is something in this explanation I can't quite figure out ...Note that the argument to `apply` is quoted.  Evaluating a quoted argument shouldn't be an issue.   And it is OK to evaluate `t`; it is self-evaluating.  If you look at the error it says the function `and` doesn't exist.  I  don't think it is even getting to the the args part.  My question is why is `(apply #'and '(t t t))` not equivalent to `(and t t t)`

Comment: Let me put my question this way:, if i have a bunch of booleans `t` and `nil` in a list---that is a list of booleans- (list t t nil t) etc -- how do I get a logical `and` of them.  So, `(setq x (list t t t))` and `(magic magic magic  x more-magic more-magic more-magic)` gives me `t`. What should I fill-in in `magic`-s and `more-magic`-s.

Comment: @mxnt: You proposed a good question in your first comment. And you can see my updated answer to it. |||| "*how do I get a logical `and` of them.*" -- Don't see my `another-and` in the original answer?

Comment: Why did you edit my question and remove the `emacs` version ... Could you please revert it.

Comment: @mxnt: Because there is nothing to do with version

Comment: Having it wouldn't matter.  Isn't it?

Comment: @mxnt: "*Having it wouldn't matter.*" -- Of course matters. This will dilute the useful information of the problem. See http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: The arguments are boolean literals, and when you evaluate literals you just get them back. The arguments to magics are always literals.

Comment: Another thing I don't understand ... why it is saying that it is not able to find `and`.  If the problem is with arguments, shouldn't the stack trace show error with the arguments instead of the function/macro place in the form?  I found quoting etc `&rest`, `apply` etc always  confusing ...

Comment: I have added the `Emacs` version ... Please don't remove it.  It is possible that `Emacs` is behavng along expected lines (granted that I haven't full  grasped why the observed behaviour is sensible).  The `M-x slime` experment suggests that there is an opportunity to improve the error report.   When you edit questons without even having a conversation first, you come across as prejudiced.  I am not sure if being prejudiced is same as acting smart  ... I am specifically alluding to your `smart questions` remark

Comment: @mxnt: I didn't say your question is not smart. Did you see that I said your question is *good* in my comment? The “smart” here is the one in “get the answer from others smartly”. Readers will be more glad to answer your question if they find your question is short enough and can be understood easily. Am I wrong?

Comment: I personally don't like people linking to that article.  "Ask smart questions" is what someone will tell  a young person, say a sophomore, and it really means "You are a student.  There is nothing much going on in your life.  Why are you annoying with me meaningless mumbo jumbo. Why don't you put some effort to digest the material at hand".  "Ask questions first", and fill in the gap as you move along is how adults and real-world works.  I have seen what Drew Adams told on `help-gnu-emacs` and you are merely repeating those words to me. No offense intended or taken.

Comment: @mxnt: “*I personally don't like people linking to that article.*” -- I am sorry. I edited the question just  because I hope others can understand your question more easily, and then you will get your answer more quickly...

Comment: @mxnt: “I personally don't like people linking to that article.”  Do you have a better one? I often link to that article because I found it useful when I read it a long time ago (and I've reread it a couple of times since then).

Comment: You seem to have a problem when I express what I like or not like.  The original objection was to @shynur deleting some information which i thought was very relevant.  There is an agreement that Emacs version was relevant, and removing it wasn't a good move.   Let us leave it at this.  I see lots of improvements being made to byte compiler code and error reporting.  Considering that the error is on a very recent Emacs, there is an opportunity to improve error reporting.

Comment: There was agreement that version information is useful in general, although it is not useful in this case: the fact that `apply` wants a function (*not* a macro or special form) is independent of version. It is documented e.g. [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-20-2.5/html_node/elisp_160.html)

Comment: "You seem to have a problem when I express what I like or not like": which "you" are you referring to? If to me, I asked for a better source so that I can read it and possibly recommend in addition to or instead of what I recommend currently. That's all I said.